# I am facing some difficulties of connecting mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, connection

```
MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed
    at Connection.onMessage (C:\Users\HP\Documents\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Customer service\BACKEND\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:205:26)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Documents\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Customer service\BACKEND\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:64:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at processIncomingData (C:\Users\HP\Documents\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Customer service\BACKEND\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:117:16)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\HP\Documents\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Customer service\BACKEND\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:564:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:493:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:502:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:1007:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError',
  connectionGeneration: 0,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' }
}
```

what can i do for this kind of error?

Comment: How do you try to connect?

Comment: There is already an existing similar issue related to this in the MongoDB Community . https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongoservererror-bad-auth-auth-failed-in-other-pc/233264?u=samrat_n_a, I hope it may help.